# Fancy arrow on the footer

Tags: html, css

I used http://cssarrowplease.com/ to generate a nice arrow to my footer but I need to add 2 more lines and I don't have any clue how to do that.

What I have so far is from cssarrowplease:

CSS:

```
footer {
    background-color: #239bd2;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

footer:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #239bd2;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

But I need to add 2 white lines ( kinda of another arrow ) to be like this:

[image]

I know it is a way with :after or :before but I have no skills in this area. Can someone guide me to an online resource? Or maybe someone knows how to do it.

Thank you,

Florin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the same way, changing the size and the color.

The problem is that you can only insert 2 pseudo-elements (`::before` and `::after`), but here we need 3. So I added an additional element.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #239bd2;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
footer:before, footer:after, footer > .arrow {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #239bd2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
footer:after {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-width: 8px;
}
footer > .arrow {
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-width: 11px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<footer><span class="arrow"></span>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make it clickable? Like changing the `span` into `a` tag?

Comment: @FlorinPop `pointer-events: none` means that it ignores mouse events, you will have to remove that. And clicks in `footer`'s pseudo-elements will be detected at `footer`, so better use `.arrow`, `.arrow:before` and `.arrow:after`.

Answer (score 0):

one single pseudo element could do it too :

```css
footer {
  justify-content: center;
  background: turquoise;
  position: relative;
}

footer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: inherit;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -1em;
  border: solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em turquoise;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* else makup for demo purpose */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body,
footer,
h1 {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  flex-direction: column;
  background: tomato;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

footer a {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<footer>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
</footer>
```

[codepen and vendor prefix](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNjJeV)